# creating space in end of xml tag in java

Tags: java, xml

My xml tag is :

```
<Description/>
```

I want with space :

```
<Description />
```

How can I do this in Java?

I am signing xml document , in original file space has been used but when I used following code and print it, it printing without space.

```
        String thisLine = "";
        String xmlString = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalXmlFilePath));
        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            xmlString = xmlString + thisLine.trim();
        }
        br.close();

        ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse
            (xmlStream );

        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);



        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext
            (keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), doc.getDocumentElement());


        javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);


        signature.sign(dsc);


        // Output the resulting document.
    //  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(destnSignedXmlFilePath));
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
         trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");


        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();//.replaceAll("\n|\r", "");


        System.out.println("output== "+output);
```

Comment: No general-purpose XML serializer is going to allow you that fine level of control of the detailed output. And you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is signing an arbitrary unprocessed text instead of submitting a canonical version of your document (without spaces in tags, but also with sorted attributes, with quotes of the same type, etc.) to the digital signature computation.

[The Canonical XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315) and [Exclusive Canonical XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/) W3C recommendations specify a standard and comprehensive way to eliminate arbitrary differences.

Comment: could you please explain me in detail ?